# Information needed to utilize TPM in Java

Tags: java, tpm

I'm reading up on my upcoming project that involves using my laptop's TPM on authentication software written in Java.

A few entries came out on Google, but most of them are quite old, and I have no idea which is the best tutorial. So I'd like to know what's the recommended API to use, and where is the best place to get information from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To communicate with a TPM you need a **Trusted Software Stack (TSS)**. There are two major freely available TSS: [**TrouSerS**](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/) and [**jTSS**](http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/index.php?item=jtss/about).

**jTSS** is written in Java, whereas **TrouSerS** is written in C.
When using the pure Java **jTSS** you don't need **jTSSWrapper**. The wrapper is only needed when you want to access **TrouSerS** TSS through Java.

The [**jTpm Tools**](http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/index.php?item=jtt/about) provide some command line tools to interact with the TPM. When looking at the source code of the tools you can figure out how to use **jTSS** API.

For more stuff related to Trusted Computing and Java have a look at http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/

There's also a JSR that tries to define a high-level Java API for Trusted Computing, you can find the information as well as a reference implementation at http://jsr321.java.net/ (including public readable SVN repo).

Comment: A long time was passed from the latest answer in this thread. Is there an update regarding a TPM API for java based applications?

Comment: For TPM 1.2 the information is still valid, for TPM 2.0 I can't say. I'm not active in that field anymore.

Answer (score 4):

start reading here.

http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/

There is any Information you need. To access your TPM (I would suggest you to do first tests with the famous TPM Emulator from http://tpm-emulator.berlios.de/)

In Java you need the Package jTSSWrapper. Just look at the test-code insight the package to get a very first impression.